# Assigning weight to a column using after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would Like to add weight to a groupby dataframe:

for example I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3], 'Money': [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]})
df
   Account  Money
0        1      4
1        2      5
2        3      6
3        1      8
4        2      9
5        3     10
6        3     11

df.groupby(['Account']).apply(lambda x: x.head(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
   Account  Money
0        1      4
1        1      8
2        2      5
3        2      9
4        3      6
5        3     10

What i want to do is: adding a weights here with half value of the last row
Like this:

   Account  Money  weights
0        1      4     1
1        1      8     0.5
2        2      5     1
3        2      9     0.5
4        3      6     1
5        3     10     0.5
6        3     12     0.25
```

(I manually add this row for demostration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only order is important and need divide `1` by array `1,2,4,8,...` by size of groups use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.rpow`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rpow.html) and divide from ride side by `1` in [`Series.rdiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rdiv.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('Account', ignore_index=True)

df['weights'] = df.groupby(['Account'])['Money'].cumcount().rpow(2).rdiv(1)
print (df)
   Account  Money  weights
0        1      4     1.00
1        1      8     0.50
2        2      5     1.00
3        2      9     0.50
4        3      6     1.00
5        3     10     0.50
6        3     11     0.25
```

If need divide by first values of `Money` per groups:

```
df = df.sort_values('Account', ignore_index=True)

df['weights'] = df.groupby(['Account'])['Money'].transform('first').div(df['Money'])
print (df)
   Account  Money   weights
0        1      4  1.000000
1        1      8  0.500000
2        2      5  1.000000
3        2      9  0.555556
4        3      6  1.000000
5        3     10  0.600000
6        3     12  0.500000
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thanks for your answer. but it is possible to have Account 2 and 3 start with the weight 1 instead of 0.9 and 0.916667, also the account 3, Money = 11 should be weight of the Money = 10's half value (that is, 0.55 / 2 )

Comment: @Javis - Answer was edited, it is what you need?

Comment: @Javis - What is expected ouput for acount 3? In first DataFrame are values 6,10,11 and in last 6,10,12, how is count weight?

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!The first solution with rpow().rdiv(1) work very well!!!Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: @Javis - Can you ask new question with input data and expected ouput?

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I think I find out the solution :)) Thank you so much